# How do I adjust this code to add easing to mouse movement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to add easing to the custom cursor on my site but im having no luck after trying a few things. If anyone knows how to adjust the following code to enable this functionality that would be super helpful as i've been stuck on it for a few hours!

I as reading about using lerp to achieve this [See this Codepen](https://codepen.io/Deepak426/pen/PoNKeLj?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=8380a9cc4062c72a176f81fa9b5e705e6f64048d-1598937842-0-AV4YgRiowVJHkfF3PnJChlKwlmCZK6kMbLM0DrCR4SXs6FkAzvSkredBgThrcWJh8rhM_S8UFHn_GANKT2c14rSAWpZu2lGpSZU3LkSOKdkSrPy6asPxymDBc20gUsGmG8uTPgbsvYmqAP-yNiG6ZMjMVuhpoQtc83nP_j8yuc9_I9cWTLDHc7G9iimATThMohtA2d3JT3rns33E_6LHBKpyL6k4l6FaqaLJJcN1ZftkVBkuOD9pgCYisC8it6pahZj0y8Q0BSbsYSFfaTjgEUFRd17EAiriMfVKcOY-ZPR-5-6yoTm-JJ5xEVK_IAwppB3vmyWC7KXEu1kMQuaNF6E) , but couldn't extract the code successfully.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
  const target = $(event.target);
  
  // update position of cursor
  cursor.css('left', e.clientX-10).css('top', e.clientY-10);
  
  const isLinkTag = target.is('a,span,[onclick],img,video,i');
  const isHovered = cursor.hasClass('hoveredCursor');
  
  // toggle the cursor class if necessary 
  if(isLinkTag && !isHovered) {
  
    cursor.addClass('hoveredCursor');

  } else if(!isLinkTag && isHovered) {
  
    cursor.removeClass('hoveredCursor');
  
  }
  
})
 
$(document).mouseleave(function(e) {

  const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
  cursor.hide()

});

$(document).mouseenter(function(e) {

  const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
  cursor.show()

});
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

.custom-cursor{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FB4D98;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius:50%;
  pointer-events: none !important;
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.hoveredCursor {

 transform: scale(0.5);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid #FB4D98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-cursor"></div>
```

Comment: I'd like to add a friendly note that this kind of behaviour may reduce usability and annoy some users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example in vanilla javascript; the javascript is only responsible for applying a new position to the custom cursor, and determining its scaling. The css handles hiding the cursor when the mouse leaves the document, centering the custom-cursor on the mouse's position, and transitions.

```js
let cursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    
  let { clientX: x, clientY: y } = evt;
  let scale = 1;
  
  if (evt.target.matches('a,span,[onclick],img,video,i')) {
    cursor.classList.add('active');
    scale = 0.5;
  } else {
    cursor.classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(${scale})`;
  
});
```

```css
* { cursor: none; }

html, body {
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
html { position: absolute; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; }
body { position: relative; height: 4000px; }

.custom-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  margin-left: -10px; margin-top: -10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #fb4d98;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 99999999;
  transition:
    transform ease-out 0.5s,
    border 0.5s,
    opacity 0.5s,
    background-color 0.5s;
}
.custom-cursor.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fb4d98;
}
body:hover > .custom-cursor { opacity: 1; }
a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-cursor"></div>
<a href="link">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this,i just tried it out but there are a few issues my end.Im almost there with Timothys code above but need to use scale instead of height/width to keep the cursor centered when it changes size on hover,do u know how to adjust the code above to use scale instead of width/height?I tried adding scale to the jQuery but its not working,this is what i tried `// toggle the cursor class if necessary 
    if (isLinkTag && !isHovered) {
      cursor.addClass('hoveredCursor');
      scale = 0.5;
    } else if (!isLinkTag && isHovered) {
      cursor.removeClass('hoveredCursor');
    }`

Comment: My code *is* using `scale`, not `width`/`height`. In jquery you would concatenate some `scale(...)` value into the `.css('transform', ...)` call

Comment: Cool I managed to almost get it working using your code now, on your CSS the opacity is '0' for some reason, so I changed that to '1' and its showing now. The final problem I have is that the custom cursor is about 30px below and 10px to the right of where the actual cursor is. I tried removing the margins in CSS but its exactly the same?

EDIT : ive just solved it using `top: -10px; left: -10px`

Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: The opacity is `0` unless the `body` is hovered - this implements the disappearance of the custom cursor upon mouseout in css. My answer fulfills the question you've posted here; if it is satisfactory give it a check/upvote. If you have further questions you should post a *separate* question on stackoverflow (and link to this question if need be).

Answer (score 1):

Change css class `.custom-cursor` like this :

```
.custom-cursor{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FB4D98;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

and add `setInterval (move,1000/60)` after you update position of cursor :

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
  const target = $(event.target);
  
  // update position of cursor
  cursor.css('left', e.clientX-10).css('top', e.clientY-10);
  setInterval (move,1000/60);
  const isLinkTag = target.is('a,span,[onclick],img,video,i');
  const isHovered = cursor.hasClass('hoveredCursor');
  
  // toggle the cursor class if necessary 
  if(isLinkTag && !isHovered) {
  
    cursor.addClass('hoveredCursor');

  } else if(!isLinkTag && isHovered) {
  
    cursor.removeClass('hoveredCursor');
  
  }
  
})
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/nemkezero/pen/xxdXyVO) is a working example.

Comment: This works great but when scrolling with the mouse wheel and moving the cursor it gets a bit buggy.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually add the code you are referring to.
You only need to set `const cursor` once.
You should set `top` and `left` in the css instead, because if you set it in JavaScript while mouse is moving, it will reset the position of that element continuously.
Since it's a unique element, you should also use an `id` for `#custom-cursor`.
You need to set transition for other properties specifically and because `transform` is changed with JavaScript, you should change `width` and `height` instead of scale.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  const cursor = $('#custom-cursor');

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    const target = $(event.target);
    const isLinkTag = target.is('a,span,[onclick],img,video,i');
    const isHovered = cursor.hasClass('hoveredCursor');

    // toggle the cursor class if necessary 
    if (isLinkTag && !isHovered) {
      cursor.addClass('hoveredCursor');
    } else if (!isLinkTag && isHovered) {
      cursor.removeClass('hoveredCursor');
    }
  });

  $(document).mouseleave(function(e) {
    cursor.hide()
  });

  $(document).mouseenter(function(e) {
    cursor.show()
  });
});

var mouseX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var mouseY = window.innerHeight / 2;

var circle = {
  el: $('#custom-cursor'),
  x: window.innerWidth / 2,
  y: window.innerHeight / 2,
  w: 80,
  h: 80,
  update: function() {
    l = this.x - this.w / 2;
    t = this.y - this.h / 2;
    this.el.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + l + 'px,' + t + 'px, 0)'
    });
  }
}

$(window).mousemove(function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
})

setInterval(move, 1000 / 60)

function move() {
  circle.x = lerp(circle.x, mouseX, 0.1);
  circle.y = lerp(circle.y, mouseY, 0.1);
  circle.update()
}

function lerp(start, end, amt) {
  return (1 - amt) * start + amt * end
}
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

#custom-cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 28px;
  left: 28px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FB4D98;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none !important;
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  transition: background-color 1s, border-color 1s, width .5s, height .5s;
}

.hoveredCursor {
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black !important;
  border: 2px solid #FB4D98 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-cursor"></div>

<a href="#">Hover me</a>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<span>Hover me too</span>
```

Comment: Amazing thanks for that! The only issue is that the CSS for ".hoveredCursor" is broken now, the only code working there now is the opacity, but the colour and scale are not being applied?

Comment: @gjjr I've updated the answer, please mark it as correct if you're satisfied.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to manually define the transition function (`lerp`) when css has that built-in - `transform: translate(...) scale(...);` + `transition: transform, ...;` are probably cleaner here.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass Ahh actually there is one final issue, I initially used height & width to change the size of the cursor on hover, but the reason I used scale is because it changes the size from the middle of the cursor rather than the corner. Is there any way to achieve this without using scale?

Comment: @Gershy I think the lerp function is needed to keep updating the position. Could you please show your solution?

Comment: @gjjr Please mark the answer as the correct solution. Your question is about the lerp functionality. For the centering of your object, you should make a child element of your `#custom-cursor` div and set the scale on that when hovering.